# Overlaying text on video is very slow any faster alternatives

Tags: ios, swift

```
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    
    guard
        let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(
            withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid),
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
        else {
            print("Something is wrong with the asset.")
            onComplete(nil)
            return
    }
    
    do {
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)
        try compositionTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: assetTrack, at: .zero)
        
        if let audioAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first,
            let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(
                withMediaType: .audio,
                preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) {
            try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(
                timeRange,
                of: audioAssetTrack,
                at: .zero)
        }
    } catch {
        //print(error)
        onComplete(nil)
        return
    }
    
    compositionTrack.preferredTransform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
    let videoInfo = orientation(from: assetTrack.preferredTransform)
    
    let videoSize: CGSize
    if videoInfo.isPortrait {
        videoSize = CGSize(
            width: assetTrack.naturalSize.height,
            height: assetTrack.naturalSize.width)
    } else {
        videoSize = assetTrack.naturalSize
    }
    
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: videoSize)

    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.string = mainTextview.text
    textLayer.shouldRasterize = true
    textLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    //textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    
    switch textAlignment {
    case .center:
        textLayer.alignmentMode = .center
    case .justified:
        textLayer.alignmentMode = .justified
    case .left:
        textLayer.alignmentMode = .left
    case .right:
        textLayer.alignmentMode = .right
    default:
        textLayer.alignmentMode = .center
    }
    
    textLayer.isWrapped = true
    textLayer.foregroundColor = mainTextview.textColor?.cgColor
    
    textLayer.fontSize = 70
    
    switch textWeight {
    case .bold:
        textLayer.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0, weight: .bold)
    case .light:
        textLayer.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0, weight: .light)
    case .regular:
        textLayer.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0, weight: .regular)
    case .medium:
        textLayer.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0, weight: .medium)
    }
    
    switch textviewPosition {
    case .Center:
        textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: videoSize.height * 0.30, width: videoSize.width, height: 500)
    case .Top:
        textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: videoSize.height * 0.60, width: videoSize.width, height: 500)
    case .Bottom:
        textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: 500)
    }
    textLayer.displayIfNeeded()
    
    let outputLayer = CALayer()
    outputLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: videoSize)
    outputLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    outputLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
    
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.renderSize = videoSize
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(
        postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer,
        in: outputLayer)
    
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(
        start: .zero,
        duration: composition.duration)
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]
    let layerInstruction = compositionLayerInstruction(
        for: compositionTrack,
        assetTrack: assetTrack)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
    
    guard let export = AVAssetExportSession(
        asset: composition,
        presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        else {
            //print("Cannot create export session.")
            onComplete(nil)
            return
    }
    
    let videoName = UUID().uuidString
    let exportURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        .appendingPathComponent(videoName)
        .appendingPathExtension(".mp4")
    
    export.videoComposition = videoComposition
    export.outputFileType = .mp4
    export.outputURL = exportURL
    
    export.exportAsynchronously {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch export.status {
            case .completed:
                onComplete(exportURL)
            default:
                onComplete(nil)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function I use to overlay the text on video (videoURL), I pass in the url for the video which is saved in the document directory and use a text view already created for the user to retrieve the text, weight, font and alignment for the overlay thanks. Majority of time this process takes 15 seconds which is a long time for users to wait.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your response under where I initiated the AVAssetExportSession I added a timer:

```
 self.exportTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(displayData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Now I can correctly update the display using this method:

```
@objc private func displayData() {
   self.progressBar.progress = exportSession.progress;
    if self.progressBar.progress > .99) {
        self.exportTimer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

I also added Invalidate() to the export.status switch statement for when there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting video is labor-intensive and takes significant time, and there's nothing you can do about that.

However, the process is asynchronous so there is no need to make the user "wait". Also, the exporter vends a Progress object, so you can easily show progress as a psychological trick (it is amazing how time flies when you're watching a progress indicator).

Comment: Thanks I am going to try the export.progress now !